# Stress-test and prove limit-scalability of Asynchronous code

Tags: batch, governorlimits, isv, locking, test-automation

Giving my question a proper title was hard as I am only partially sure what I am actually looking for - solution-wise.

In our fully native (no AWS or Functions backend) Managed Package many independent asynchronous jobs modify data. We also create and **modify Manual Sharing** rules on a big scale.

To make that work we have built our own **custom Asynchronous queue** which mainly used Batch and Scheduler.

While having great Unit Test coverage we also need Scalability tests that do not only simulate Async on a minimal scale. We would like to simulate thousands of users, enqueuing random jobs, and see how Governor limits, Locking, and Rollback behavior under real stress is.

**Is there a way to do this with normal orgs? Did you do something similar in the past? What learnings can you share?**

Comment: At DF '22 there was a session announcing a new org type/flavor for stress tests at scale. (Can't find the link to the announcement).

Comment: I asked the Twitterverse. Maybe something around Scale Center?

Comment: @identigral is it what they say on twitter? https://twitter.com/rsoesemann/status/1579881879515561984

Comment: Yup, that's the one.

Comment: @identigral and how would that help in my case?

Comment: _We would like to simulate thousands of users, enqueuing random jobs, and see how Governor limits, Locking, and Rollback behavior under real stress is_ - sounds like the new org type might help with this. Give it a shot!